# Troubleshooting the built-in Visual Studio 2008 WebDev.WebServer.EXE

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I begin to troubleshoot Visual Studio 2008's WebDev.WebServer.EXE?

I'm trying to run the default ASP.NET MVC project. And I keep getting this message from Firefox:

Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:52589.
    *   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
          moments.
    *   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
          connection.
    *   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
          that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Similar messages from IE and Google Chrome.

I have disabled the Vista firewall. VS2008 is ver SP1.

When I ping localhost on Vista the IP comes back in IPv6 format. Is that normal? The ping works.
Security: I have opened up the folder that the app is running in to Everyone - Full.

What else should I be trying? I don't think I have ever run into this issue on a machine before.

Comment: Do you have any other firewalls?

Comment: Are you running this under cassini or IIS?  If IIS then which version?

Comment: no other firewalls. under cassini. IIS not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things that you can try.  First, although you may have already tried this, is to ensure it is running.  Check your task manager, to see if you can find it there.  Also, an icon should appear in your system tray.  Secondly, once you've established that it is running, try connecting to it through [telnet](http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm).  For your set up, you could use the following to connect using telnet.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 52589
```

You can also try pointing firefox to localhost, or ::1 which is the IPV6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: tried the 3rd thing with the same result as http://localhost:52589
will try the telnet. if the webserver is running what name does it use in the processes?

Comment: I believe you will see WebDev.WebServer.EXE in the process list.  Also, of note is that the web server doesn't start until you try to debug.  If you stop debugging, sometimes it shuts down (I find that XP Shuts down while Vista keeps it running).  If you've just started visual studio without running the debugger.  Also, see this question about running cassini from the command line (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256401/857179#857179)

Comment: arghh Telnet not installed. Got to figure out how to solve that now.

Comment: ok. got that installed and it failed with the message - Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 52589 :
Connect failed

Comment: go to that link I posted in my previous comment and try to run cassini from the command line to see if you get any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are trying to access the correct port?  If you hover over the system tray icon for Cassini, the tooltip will give you the correct port.

You can also right click on the icon and select Open in Web Browser.

Answer (score 0):

My first feeling is that it could be the port number.  If you have the project setup to 'Auto-assign Port' I would change it to a specific port, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy WebDev.WebServer.EXE and WebDev.WebServer.exe.manifest from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0" and enjoy your time

Comment: is it still a valid solution after 5 years?